# Actions always returning unauthorised

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm creating a simple e-commerce site as a personal project.

I have a `products` table that creates a relationship between each product listed by a user.

```
$table->foreign('owner_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

The relationship works as expected, each product is assigned an `owner_id` that is equal to the user's ID who listed the product. I've checked the database in PHPMyAdmin and it's pointing to the correct user every time.

I generated a policy with artisan and pointed my model to it in order to use automatic route model binding

```
php artisan make:policy productsPolicy --model=products
```

```
public function canView(User $user, products $product)
{
    return $product->owner_id == $user->id;
}
```

My AuthServiceProvider points to the policy in question

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\productsPolicy',
];
```

I then reference the policy in my controller to only allow the creator to delete their listing

```
public function destroy(products $product)
{
    $this->authorize('canView', $product);
    $product->delete();

    return redirect('/');
}
```

No matter if I'm logged in as the user who created the project or not, the following exception is always thrown

> AccessDeniedHttpException

Comment: Sidenote on naming conventions; `products` is a bad model name. Models are singular ("A Product", an instance of the plural "Products") and `StudlyCase`, so `products` should be `Product`. Same with `productsPolicy`; should be `ProductsPolicy` (class names are also `StudlyCase`). Note this doesn't break anything, but just something to be aware of for consistency's sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not properly register your policy

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\productsPolicy', // 'App\Model' probably isn't a model
];
```

It should be

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\products' => 'App\Policies\productsPolicy',
];
```

or import the class

```
use App\Policies\productsPolicy;
use App\products;

protected $policies = [
    products::class => productsPolicy::class,
];
```

Comment: Thanks so much :) 
I correctly registered my policy with
`App\products`

Comment: And as a sidenote, as Tim Lewis pointed out your classes are named pretty badly and therefore highly confusing. For example you are using `products` as a model but `User` as well, it should be `Product` and `ProductPolicy`.

Comment: I agree completely. This is my first laravel project and I realised only half way through that my naming conventions need serious work. I came into it with no experience with an MVC. I'd change it all now but with the amount of files I've got set up I feel as though it would take a few painstaking hours to get everything working again